# Assign a numerical value to a number x times

Tags: sas

I'd like to do something pretty simple. I'd just like to set the value of a variable to a numerical value repeatedly x number of times. In R I could do something like:

```
drug <- c(rep(0, times = 10), rep(1, times = 10))
```

which would produce:

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

So far, the best I have is:

```
data drug_data (drop = i);
    do i = 1 to 10;
        drug = 0;
        output;
    end;
    do i = 1 to 10;
        drug = 1;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Is this the best solution? Thanks

Comment: My answer is nearly identical to your 'best', and that's what I would suggest (though you don't need to do the drug=# assignment in the loop).  I also use the automatic variable `_n_` (which normally roughly translates to observation number, though is not identical to it) because it's appropriate (I'm creating observations!) and because it's automatically dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS is not a vector language, so the concepts aren't quite identical.

If you want a single variable to contain a string like so, that's trivial:

```
data have;
  drug = repeat('1 ',9)||repeat('0 ',9);
run;
```

`repeat` works just like `rep` in `r`, except the number you pass it is one less than the number you want (because it takes the original value then adds an additional N copies of that).

However, assuming you want something you can do something with, you probably want to create multiple *rows*.  Elements in a vector roughly translate to rows in SAS, typically.  SAS works on something roughly similar to the r `data.frame` object, with columns/variables being equivalent to vectors in a data.frame, and observations being equivalent to their elements.

There you use the `output` statement in a loop; that creates new observations/rows/elements.

```
data have;
  drug=1;
  do _n_=1 to 10;
    output;
  end;
  drug=0;
  do _n_ = 1 to 10;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Of course if you don't care about sorting you can put all that in one 1->10 loop instead of two of them.

Comment: Thanks @Joe! I came up with a similar solution in between my original post and reading your post. I guess I was a little surprised that the repeat function in SAS only works with character variables.

Comment: Remember, SAS functions only operate at the single-observation level.  Only `proc` can operate on multiple observations at once - anything in a `data` step operates on a single value of a single row at once, never anything more.  So you couldn't do anything like `rep` in SAS.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this which creates 20 variables drug1-drug20.

```
34         data _null_;
35            array drug[20] (10*0 10*1);
36            put drug[*];
37            run;

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Or how about this since apparently vectors are tall.

```
data drug;
   array d[20] _temporary_ (10*0 10*1);
   do _n_ = 1 to dim(d);
      drug=d[_n_];
      output;
      end;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: I think r vector elements translate to SAS rows/observations, not to SAS columns.  Though this is certainly worth pointing out in case there is a reason to do it as columns.

Comment: I can't even spell r.

Comment: Lol.  My four year old asked me how to spell GMC (the car brand) the other day.  I nearly fell over laughing before I realized he was serious.